# No routes matches DELETE for removing a CarrierWave multiple file uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

Using a member route like this similar to one I have used for deleting tags:

```ruby
  resources 'factory' do
    resources 'tags' do
      member do
        delete :remove
      end
    end
    resources 'project_files' do
      member do
        delete :remove
      end
    end
  end
```

I (should) invoke in the projects controller:

```ruby
class ProjectFilesController < ApplicationController
  def remove
    @factory = Factory.find(params[:fabmoment_id])
    @project_file = ProjectFile.find(params[:id])
    authorize @factory, :project_file?

    @project_file.remove!
    head :ok
  end
end
```

Which I can't check for correctness (yet). The partial _project_files looks like:

```ruby
<li class="project_file">
    <% if policy(factory).project_file? %>
        <%= link_to "<span></span>".html_safe, 
                remove_factory_project_file_path(factory, project_file), method: :delete, remote: true, 
                class: "remove",
                title: "remove" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to File.basename(project_file.url), project_file.url %>
  (<%= number_to_human_size(project_file.file.size) %>)
</li>
```

Which is invoked by passing locales with a render method in the `factory#show` view. (Could also add an index.) 
Like this it is mostly equal to the tags remove action though and I like to keep things consequent and simple.

The error I receive from my spec:

**No route matches [DELETE] "/factories/1/project_files/%2Fuploads%2Ffactory%2Fproject_files%2F1%2Fthe_puritan_1st_floor.stl/remove"**

My Factory model only contains `mount_uploaders :project_files, ProjectFileUploader`

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: what is the output of running `rake routes` from the command line?

Comment: your problem must be the slashes(/) in your file name. I think you need to modify you route to allow some constraints for the slashes. For reference go to `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html` to the section `3.8 Segment Constraints`. A possible solution would be `delete :remove, constraints: /[0-9A-Za-z\-\.\%\s]+/`. I'm not sur about it, that's I put it as a comment, but for sure it has to do with the slashes. So, I suggest you to look a solution using constraints.